# possibility to order (for a field string as it was a integer) in a table in hibernate with the criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Making the due replace of some characters and remaining with numbers… They can be used the criteria in order to order in a table of the data, using a field string that cleaned up of the alfanumeri characters too much, remains with the numbers and thus comes ordered in correct way?

Comment: Hmm... I guess that didn't help much.  Unless somebody else can make sense of it?

Answer (score 0):

Sajnos nem tudok segiteni, mert egy szót sem értek.
**Edit** Sorry, it was clearer to me when it was in Italian...